# How to draw shapes like this in xaml?

Tags: xaml

How can I draw this shape in xaml?

[Shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJeIl.png)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What you have tried yet???

Comment: I tired with a rectangle as a base image but don't know how to continue from that. Don't know how to get rid of the corners of the rectangle.

Comment: Btw as this is my secound post here I really "appreciated" the down voting. I belive  all people was beginer once. Ty for not understanding that :(

Comment: Appreciate your spirit. I will definitely appreciate your question if you provide us some minimum code to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Grid Width="150" Height="200">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border CornerRadius="10,10,0,0">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.822,0.633" StartPoint="0.158,0.189">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF09CCF4" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF020CA7" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <TextBlock Text="Blah" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="White" CornerRadius="0,0,10,10"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Other Stuff" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Manu: When I saw your example I noticed that that you are using more than one object and you put them together so I guess I can't draw that shape as only one object but It must use a few objects and put them together. I have sloved that. Ty for the guideline.